# Find all possible values of the integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

**[NBHM PhD Screening Test_2006_Analysis]**

> Find all possible values of $\displaystyle I= \int_C
>  \frac{dz}{1+z^2}$, where $C$ is a curve with initial point $0$ and
>   final point $1$ that does not meet the poles of $\dfrac{1} {1+z^2}$

.

It looks like a problem related to residue theorem, but I have no idea what should I do as $C$ is not closed. Can anyone provide some hints? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Try to rewrite the integral as a sum of integrals, one of which is closed. You can form different types of closed contours, depending on whether or not they include one, zero or both poles of $1/(1+z*z)$

Comment: Can you draw a path that starts at $0$, goes once around $\mathrm{i}$ in the positive direction, returns to $0$, then proceeds to $1$?  Can you do the same, but going around in the negative direction?  Can you draw similar positive and negative directed paths for the pole at $-\mathrm{i}$?  What happens if you repeat a loop several times?  What happens if oyu mix loops in both directions and around both poles?  Does it matter what order your path loops around the two poles?

Comment: By doing that, we can get 4 closed loops(passing through 0 and contains  i or -i in positive/negative direction) and another curve with starting point 0 and final point 1. If we repeat the loop several times, we can use residue theorem to calculate the integral value for the closed loops. When we mix the loops, we got them cancelled? And I dont really understand the last hint. ='(
And how about the path from 0 to 1 after the loop?